# Spring boot application is getting stuck while running

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is my first spring-boot application. I ran a sample code and it is getting stuck at "Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' ".

Below is the code

```
package com.fredo.webservices.homefredoServcies;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HomeFredoServciesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HomeFredoServciesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

below are the logs

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2020-06-07 20:58:15.807  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] c.f.w.h.HomeFredoServciesApplication     : Starting HomeFredoServciesApplication on ANGU with PID 1496 (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\java ms\home-fredoServcies\target\classes started by Angu in C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\java ms\home-fredoServcies)
2020-06-07 20:58:15.811  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] c.f.w.h.HomeFredoServciesApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-07 20:58:15.881  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-06-07 20:58:15.882  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-06-07 20:58:16.799  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-06-07 20:58:16.822  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 13ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-06-07 20:58:17.861  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-06-07 20:58:17.876  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-07 20:58:17.877  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-06-07 20:58:18.038  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-07 20:58:18.038  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2156 ms
2020-06-07 20:58:18.100  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-06-07 20:58:18.335  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-06-07 20:58:18.342  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:b2c0eff5-9805-4a71-9f66-c6c863d910f5'
2020-06-07 20:58:18.548  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-07 20:58:18.629  INFO 1496 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-06-07 20:58:18.674  WARN 1496 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-06-07 20:58:18.720  INFO 1496 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-06-07 20:58:18.966  INFO 1496 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-06-07 20:58:19.203  INFO 1496 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-06-07 20:58:19.210  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-06-07 20:58:19.317  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-06-07 20:58:19.322  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-06-07 20:58:19.324  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-06-07 20:58:19.344  INFO 1496 --- [  restartedMain] c.f.w.h.HomeFredoServciesApplication     : Started HomeFredoServciesApplication in 3.985 seconds (JVM running for 4.795)
2020-06-07 20:58:19.554  INFO 1496 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-06-07 20:58:19.562  INFO 1496 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Comment: did you check your localhost:8080 ? because the logs show  that `Started HomeFredoServciesApplication in 3.985 seconds`

Comment: im actually running it in port 8081. When i run it in 8080, the logs stated that the port was already in use.

Comment: you can kill the port via running this command on cmd 
1. netstat -ano | findstr :PORT_NUMBER 
2. taskkill /PID PORT_NUMBER /F
But as per your logs your server is running on 8080

Comment: server does not stuck at "Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'" if you look closely it's INFO message

Comment: check your hosts file, and tell whether the 127.0.0.0 is mapped to some other adresses than localhost. if so the server hangs up on trying to reach the mapped address, generally it is some of adobe addresses, I deleted that entry once and it worked

Comment: ok, now i get it....since im new to sprint tools, i though i was stuck there...Thanks all

Answer (score 16):

I had same problem with application started by Eclipse and Spring Tool Run Configuration in Debug Mode.

A breakpoint was referencing a line on some removed block code, after removing faulty breakpoint, the application start new properly again.

Window-> Show View -> Breakpoints

Comment: this solve my problem, thanks

Comment: appreciate it. It solve my problem too.

Comment: thanks bro, u save the day

Answer (score 0):

try to hit http://localhost:8080/h2-console if you get response. your server is up and running. In logs it says H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:b2c0eff5-9805-4a71-9f66-c6c863d910f5'

Comment: Yes....you were right....since im new to Springtools, i thought i was stuck there...then i used a text output to check it and it worked fine....Thanks a lot